# How to convert a Mono<List<Object>> to a Flux<Object>?

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm just getting started with reactive so please correct me if the question doesn't make sense.

I'm creating a rest controller with Spring WebFlux + Reactive MongoDB as a database and I have the following document structure in it.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ee350839d3d4e34f0790566"
    },
    "customerId": "7777",
    "contacts": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ee350839d3d4e34f0790565"
            },
            "name": "Alice",
            "mobileNumbers": "0123456789"
        }, {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ee3508a9d3d4e34f0790567"
            },
            "name": "Tom",
            "mobileNumbers": "1123456789"
        }
    ],
    "_class": "com.demo.contact.model.Customer"
}
```

This sample document has a customer with his contacts. I'm trying to get a Flux when searching from the list of contact for a customer.

```
public Mono<List<Contact>> searchContacts(String customerId, String searchCriteria) {

    return customerRepository.findById(customerId).map(existingCustomer -> {
        List<Contact> contacts= existingCustomer.getContacts().stream()
                .filter( // some filtering code )
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return contacts;
    });
}
```

The question is how do I change this piece of code to get a `Flux<Object>` instead of a `Mono<List<Object>>` ?

Comment: You haven't explained your logic for reducing a `List` with potentially many values into a single value.

Comment: Does your list need to be sorted? If not you can skip all the stream stuff i.e `findById(customerId).map(Customer::getContacts).flatMapIterable(Function.identity()).filter()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods to go from `Mono` to `Flux` which you will learn with experience. You will need to get better at Java `streams`, better with `Optional` and, of course, the `Reactive` API. The `Optional` part is important because you need to understand that using `.map` means you still have an `Optional` result so you should include a `.orElse` as well.

You didn't specify whether you are using a reactive MonogoDb driver, so I assume you are.

One good way to go from a `Mono<List<?>>` is to use `Mono::flatMapMany` or `Mono::flatMapIterable`;

```
public Flux<Contact> searchContacts(String customerId, String searchCriteria) {
    return customerRepository.findMonoById(customerId)
            .map(optionalCustomer -> optionalCustomer
                    .map(existingCustomer -> existingCustomer.getContacts().stream().filter(c -> c == c)
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyList()))
            .flatMapMany(contacts -> Flux.fromIterable(contacts));
}
```

or

```
public Flux<Contact> searchContacts(String customerId, String searchCriteria) {
    return customerRepository.findMonoById(customerId)
            .map(optionalCustomer -> optionalCustomer
                    .map(existingCustomer -> existingCustomer.getContacts().stream().filter(c -> c == c)
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyList()))
            .flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
}
```

In case you are not using a reactive driver then you can just make a `Flux` from an iterable.

```
public Flux<Contact> searchContacts(String customerId, String searchCriteria) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(customerRepository.findById(customerId)
            .map(existingCustomer -> existingCustomer.getContacts().stream().filter(c -> c == c)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList()));
}
```